# Putting dynamic string parameter in drop down menu server controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am new to .net/c# and visual studio. I have been looking all over the internet for an answer but couldn't find it. Thanks for your help.

I'm populating a drop down list from a database table, I want to pass a dynamic parameter to the asp server control (the logged in persons username). The 2 areas I want to put this dynamic string I added PUT_LOGGED_IN_USERNAME_HERE".

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PK_Task" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Supportive</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_Task], [Name] FROM [Task] WHERE ([PointPerson] LIKE '%' + @PointPerson + '%') AND [Status] LIKE 'Done'">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="PUT_LOGGED_IN_USERNAME_HERE" Name="PointPerson" 
            QueryStringField="PUT_LOGGED_IN_USERNAME_HERE"" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How do I accomplish this?

I found the code to display username:

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>
```

However it is not working when I use it as shown:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>" Name="PointPerson" 
     QueryStringField="<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>"" Type="String" />
```

Comment: Does it work if you set it in code-behind? E.g. `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["PointPerson"].DefaultValue = "User";` ?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thanks! SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["PointPerson"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;

Comment: Cool :) I will post it as an answer then. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access properties of SqlDataSource, including Parameters in code behind, like so:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["PointPerson"].DefaultValue = "User";
```